# How to run a Runnable every second to update the UI

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to code in kotlin android to move an image every second but I am not able to make it work. Right now I'm using a `Timer` to schecule a `Timer Task` every second but it is not working as expected.

Here is my code

```
class Actvt_Image<float> : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actvt__image)

        val pict_mario = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_Mario)
        val bt_down = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_down)
        val frame = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.frame)
        val txt1=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt1)

        var i =100
        val timer = Timer()
        val myTask = object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {

                txt1.text = (i+1).toString()
                img_Mario.rotation=180f
                img_Mario.translationX +=100
                img_Mario.translationY +=20
            }
        }

        bt_down.setOnClickListener {

            i=0
            timer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: define "cannot work"

Comment: Try to call timer.run() in your clicklistener

Comment: it can not move as I expected

Comment: Does it move at all ? How do you want to move ?

Comment: I want move image_mario but it can not

Comment: @ Robin Vinzenz: can you write this code of "timer.run()" because I tried but it doest work

Comment: Share the `xml` where `R.id.img_Mario` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the UI on a background thread which is not possible. UI can only be updated on the UI thread. Also, using a `Timer` and `TimerTask` to create and destroy a thread every 1 second is not the right way to use threads because creating a thread is a memory expensive operation.

What you need to do is to use a `Handler` and tell the `UI Thread` to run a `Runnable` after every desired interval. Remove `Timer` and `TimerTask` and use the following

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                txt1.text = (i+1).toString()
                img_Mario.rotation=180f
                img_Mario.translationX +=100
                img_Mario.translationY +=20

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        })
```

Above code is using a handler and posting a task to the UI Thread message queue. The task itself is updating the UI and posting itself again to the UI Thread message queue using the same handler but this time after 1 second delay using the `handler.postDelayed()` methond

**EDIT : How to stop runnable**

If you want to stop a specific `runnable` you can use the following method and pass in the same `runnable` object that you passed in `handler.post()`. Surely you have to keep a reference to the `runnable` at all time to stop it. The above code doesn't keep a reference. See the **Complete code** below.

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) //stops a specific runnable
```

To stop all remaining callbacks or `runnable` from the UI Thread message queue use this

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) //stops any pending callback in message queue
```

**Complete code**

*NOTE: I have added a stop button click listener as an addition*

```
class Actvt_Image<float> : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var handler : Handler
        private lateinit var runnable : Runnable // reference to the runnable object
        private var i = 0

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_actvt__image)

            val pict_mario = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_Mario)
            val bt_down = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_down)
            val bt_stop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt_stop)
            val frame = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.frame)
            val txt1=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt1)

            handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            runnable = Runnable {
                i++
                txt1.text = i.toString()
                img_Mario.rotation=180f
                img_Mario.translationX +=100
                img_Mario.translationY +=20
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
            }

            bt_down.setOnClickListener {

                handler.post(runnable)

            }

            bt_stop.setOnClickListener {
                //Use this to stop all callbacks
                //handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) 

            }
        }

    }
```

Read more about processes, threads and handler here :
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: your code is right. But how I control when it runnable. Example: when I click a button and then it will run ?

Comment: @DangHoang just initialize the handler before `bt_down.setOnClickListener` and put the rest of the code inside `bt_down.setOnClickListener`. I edited my answer , see the complete code there.

Comment: @DangHoang My bad I forgot to add that. Check my updated answer. This time instead of creating the `runnable` object directly inside the`handler.post()` method. I have kept a reference to it as separate `runnable` object and used that to start and stop the `runnable`

Comment: @DangHoang I'm glad to hear that. If this solution worked for you please tick the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark icon. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have one code and it run as I expected

```
     val t = object : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            while (!isInterrupted) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000)  //1000ms = 1 sec
                    runOnUiThread {
                        i++

                        txt1.text = i.toString()
                        img_Mario.rotation=180f
                        img_Mario.translationX +=20

                    }

                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }
    }

    bt_down.setOnClickListener {
        i=0
        t.start()
    }
```

Comment: This will also work but the thing is you are creating a new thread and asking that thread to run a piece of code on the UI Thread and do nothing by itself. In short there is no need to create a new thread if that new thread is not doing anything else. Instead you can use the UI Thread itself to run a piece of code by using `handler.post()` as I mentioned in my answer.