# how to show or hide keyboard after certain of time in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to show or hide keyboard based on user interaction or certain of time here is how i
implement my functions:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard(
) {
   requestFocus()
   val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as
        InputMethodManager
   imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
  }

fun EditText.hideKeyboard(
) {
val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as
        InputMethodManager
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
}
```

i search a lot through many community but no one mention that how we can solve this issue

Comment: You could use something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56912048/15749574

Answer (score 0):

You may use postDelay() method of Handler and give it the time after how much milliseconds you want to show or hide the keyboard

i.e.

```
Handler.postDelay({
// Hide or Show Keyboard
},YOUR_TIME)
```